# how to add column and fill it with value in oracle stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a task on my studies that says to make a procedure that adds new column 'BRUTTO' to a table and fills it's records with values based on defined variable = 24 and values from column 'NETTO'. I wrote this but it doesn't work. Any help is appreciated.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE WSTAW_KOLUMNE_BRUTTO  
AS  
   CURSOR C IS   
     SELECT NETTO  
     FROM TABELA_1  
     FOR UPDATE
     ;
     V_VAT NUMBER(9,2) := 24;
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE TABELA_1 ADD BRUTTO NUMBER';
    FOR V_REKORD IN C
    LOOP
       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE TABELA_1 SET BRUTTO = ' 
           || V_REKORD.NETTO * (1 + 24/100)||' WHERE CURRENT OF C';
    END LOOP;
END WSTAW_KOLUMNE_BRUTTO;
```

Comment: no needn't to exist in the procedure body, do not forget to issue `commit` (or `rollback` depending on the negative responsive situation) at the end. Otherwise full table will be locked.

Answer (score 2):

I would rewrite it as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE WSTAW_KOLUMNE_BRUTTO  
AS  
    V_VAT NUMBER(9,2) := 24;  -- maybe this should be parameter?
BEGIN
   -- how about adding check if column already exists?
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE TABELA_1 ADD BRUTTO NUMBER';

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
       'UPDATE TABELA_1 SET BRUTTO = NETTO * (1 + :1 /100)' USING  V_VAT;
END WSTAW_KOLUMNE_BRUTTO;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=cdb20147d7bb417cbcd8516564f608c0)**

Comment: OK, you need dynamic SQL to ALTER TABLE from PL/SQL. But, what's the point in *updating* a table via dynamic SQL? Why not simply `update tablea_1 set brutto = netto * (1 + v_vat/100)`?

Comment: @Littlefoot Becasue it won't work. Column `BRUTTO` has to exist before code is compiled successfully **[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a3c6d8dcbde8984d0493bc57e90fda64)**